# Can I add formula to in Data Validation, Allow, List?

Tags: excel

I think for instance I select an A1:A1000 range, but just I want cells with data got it. So I have an 1000 cells range, but inside the range has 30 cells with data, and when I would like to select an value from my drop down list, I will see the 30 value without empty value.

I think for this one...

[image: image1]

and this one...

[image: image2]

Comment: Are the 30 cells with data out of the 1000 cells the **first** 30 cells? If so, then this is possible. Otherwise it is not possible without having a helper column since the `List` must be a successive range.

Comment: I use an helper Column, and I make an Range with AA3:AA1000, after I set up the validation, just now I have 1000 record with 970 empty values in my drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is always at the top of the the range, with no blanks half way down, use the Name Manager and create a range using the following:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)
```

If you set the Named Range to be `titles` for example, in data validation select `List` and put `=titles` in the source.

Of course change `Sheet1!` to the name of the sheet where your values are.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!